# Баг Мозиллы с media quaries?

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

Сегодня поймал такой баг на Мозилле.
Есть @media (max-width: 767px), который при масштабировании не работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Клиент скейлит до 125% и стили перестают работать, как победить этот баг? На скрине видно что стили не работают.

Comment: вам код тоже скрином показать и что что бы не было видно ??

Comment: Проблема может быть не в мозилле или даже хроме, в котором тоже воспроизводится, а в эмуляторе

Comment: Проблема в том что клиент скейлит (все правила работают правильно).

Comment: попробуй добавить `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @Grundy это прописано уже(

Comment: @Grundy у клиента по умолчанию монитор 2560*1440, и всегда масштабирование ОС 125%